# After upgrading to xcode 9, cordova app won't build, error 70, requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

VS2015 Remote Build,
Cordova 6.5.0,
Xcode 9.3.1,

I've tried hard but still can't solve the problem. Anyone can help?

Error Message:

```
1>  ** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **
1>MDAVSCLI : error : exportArchive: "XXX.app" requires a provisioning 
profile with the Push Notifications feature
1>  Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""XXX.app" requires a 
provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature." UserInfo= 
{NSLocalizedDescription="XXX.app" requires a provisioning profile with the 
Push Notifications feature., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to 
the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}
1>
1>  ** EXPORT FAILED **
1>
1>   Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,- 
archivePath,XXX.xcarchive,- 
exportOptionsPlist,/Users/UserName/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco- 
remote/builds/20190/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,- 
exportPath,/Users/UserName/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco- 
remote/builds/20190/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrade my cordova project to Cordova@7.1.0, and change my build.json below:

```
{
"ios": {
    "debug": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
        "developmentTeam": "yourTemaID",
        "packageType": "development",
        "automaticProvisioning": true,
        "buildFlag": [
            "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
            "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
            "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
        ]
    },
    "release": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
        "developmentTeam": "yourTemaID",
        "packageType": "app-store",
        "automaticProvisioning": true,
        "buildFlag": [
            "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
            "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
            "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
        ]
    }
}}
```

Now,everything work like a charm!

[Cordova Doc iOS build.json](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html#using-buildjson)

Answer (score 0):

This means you must open the `.xcodeproj` file created on the MacOS with Xcode, then enable the **Automatic Signing** option to manage signing and provisioning profiles. Only after that, you can build and deploy from Xcode directly without problems.